# Applying redactions in the form of string substitutions to HTML documents using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transformation, redaction

I have a large number of HTML (and possibly other xml) documents that I need to redact.

The redactions are typically of the form "John Doe" -> "[Person A]".  The text to be redacted may be in headers or paragraphs, but will almost always be in paragraphs.

Simple string substitutions really.    Not very complicated things.

However, I do want to preserve document structure, and I would prefer to not reinvent any wheels.   String substitution in the document text may do the job, but also may break document structure, so it will be a last option.

Right now I have stared at XSLT for an hour and tried to force "str:replace" to do my bidding.  I will spare you from viewing me feeble attempts that didn't work, but I will ask this:  Is there a simple and  know way to apply my redactions using XSLT, and could you post it here?

Thank you in advance.

**Update:** at the request of Martin Honnen I'm adding my input files, as well as the command I used to get the latest error message.  From this it will be apparent that I'm a complete n00b when it comes to XSLT :-)

.html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>TodaysDate</title>
        <meta name="created" content="2020-11-04T30:45:00"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <ol start="2">
          <li><p> John Doe on 9. fux 2057 together with Henry
          Fluebottom formed the company Doe &; Fluebottom Widgets
          Inc. </p>
        </ol>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The XSLT transformation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        >
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:copy>
<xsl:attribute name="matchesPattern">
  <xsl:copy-of select='str:replace("John Doe", ".*",  "[Person A]")'/>
</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:copy-of select='str:replace("Henry Fluebottom", ".*",  "[Person B]")'/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The  command and the output:

```
$  xsltproc -html transform.xsl example.html
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function replace bound to undefined prefix str
xmlXPathCompiledEval: 2 objects left on the stack.
<?xml version="1.0"?>



    TodaysDate




      <p matchesPattern=""/>  

$
```

Comment: It is not clear why `str:replace` (in XSLT 1 with EXSLT) or `replace` in XSLT 2 and later does not do the job for you, unless each string you want to replace is not contained in a single text node (e.g. `<p>John Doe is sick</p>`) but in mixed contents or spread across several elements  like `<p><prename>John</prename> <surname>Doe</surname> is sick.</p>`). Thus, at least show us a representative, small input and output sample, even if you feel your coding attempt failed. But you could show one also and tell us how it failed exactly.

Comment: Could you give a minimal example of input and of output, pease?

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I have now added a minimal input/out example.

Comment: Could you pls share your inputs on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75578775/xsl-recursive-template-variables-to-be-passed

Comment: Could you pls share your inputs on this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75578775/xsl-recursive-template-variables-to-be-passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xsltproc is based on libxslt and that way supports various EXSLT functions like `str:replace`, to use it you will need to declare the namespace

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    exclude-result-prefixes="str"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p//text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="str:replace(., 'John Doe', '[Person A]')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have xsltproc "compiled against libxml 20904, libxslt 10129 and libexslt 817", it supports `str:replace`, the source code https://github.com/GNOME/libxslt/blob/mainline/libexslt/strings.c#L597 also suggests it is supported. So I am not sure whether your comment is meant to differentiate between libxslt and libexslt or whether you are talking about the lack of support for `str:replace` in an older version.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is a solution to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way in XSLT 1.0 to perform multiple replacements on the same string. You need to use a recursive named template, performing one replacement operation at a time, then moving to the next instance of the current find string or - when no next instance exists - to the next find/replace pair.

Consider the following example:

**Input**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>John Doe and Henry Fluebottom</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>John Doe is a person. John Doe on 9. fux 2057 together with Henry Fluebottom formed the company Doe &amp; Fluebottom Widgets Inc. Henry Fluebottom is also a person.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**XSLT 1.0 (+ EXSLT node-set() function)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="dictionary">
    <entry find="John Doe" replace="[Person A]"/>
    <entry find="Henry Fluebottom" replace="[Person B]"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="multi-replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="entries" select="exsl:node-set($dictionary)/entry"/>"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="multi-replace">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="entries"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$entries">
            <xsl:call-template name="multi-replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string">
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="search-string" select="$entries[1]/@find"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="replace-string" select="$entries[1]/@replace"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="entries" select="$entries[position() > 1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="search-string"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace-string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, $search-string)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $search-string)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replace-string"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $search-string)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="search-string" select="$search-string"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace-string" select="$replace-string"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>[Person A] and [Person B]</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>[Person A] is a person. [Person A] on 9. fux 2057 together with [Person B] formed the company Doe &amp; Fluebottom Widgets Inc. [Person B] is also a person.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, this replaces all instances of the search strings anywhere in the input document (except for attributes), while preserving the document's structure.

---

Note that the input in your example does not actually contain the `"Henry Fluebottom"` search string. You might want to get around that by calling the first template with:

```
<xsl:with-param name="string" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
```

instead of:

```
<xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is a solution to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is to find an XSLT processor that actually supports string replacement. The replace() function is standard in XSLT 2.0+, but does not exist in XSLT 1.0. Some XSLT 1.0 processors support an extension function str:replace() in a different namespace, but at the very least, you need to add the namespace declaration `xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"` to your stylesheet in order to locate the function. I don't know if that will work (I don't know if there is any way of using this function with xsltproc); my advice would be to use an XSLT 2.0+ processor instead.

The next problem is the way you are invoking the function. Typically, a correct invocation would be

```
replace(., "John Doe", "[Person A]")
```

though you will have to jump through a few more hoops to make multiple replacements on the same string.

I've no idea what you are trying to achieve with the `<xsl:attribute name="matchesPattern">` instruction.