# XML which has JSON with an array inside of it: iterate throught that array

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I have this XML:

```
<root>
"countryList":
[
{
"countryName": "UK",
"countryId": "909",
"countryCapital": "london"
},
{
"countryName": "India",
"countryId": "910",
"countryCapital": "Delhi"
}
]
</root>
```

I need to iterate thru this array to get the below json output:

```
{
"countries":
[
{
"Name": "UK",
"Id": "909",
"Capital": "london"
},
{
"Name": "India",
"Id": "910",
"Capital": "Delhi"
}
]
}
```

Can someone please help me achieve the same. Appreciated!

What i have tried so far is :

```
 <xsl:text>{ countries: </xsl:text>
 <xsl: for-each = ="substring-before(substring-after(., '&quot;countryList&quot;: '), ',')" >
 <xsl:text>{ Name: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&quot;countryName&quot;: '), ',')"/>
<xsl:text>, Id: </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&quot;countryId&quot;: '), ',')"/>
<xsl:text>} </xsl:text>
</xsl: for-each>
```

Comment: That's not well-formed JSON.  It must start with `{` or `[`

Comment: just replace `<root>` and `</root>` with `{` and `}`

Answer (score 2):

Handling JSON using string manipulations in XSLT 1.0 (or XSLT 2.0) is not a robust procedure. The same JSON content can be formatted in a variety of ways (esp. with regard to whitespace characters) and an algorithm designed to handle one form can easily fail with another.

The following should work with the example you posted. However, a much better solution would be to move to XSLT 3.0, where JSON can be ingested and processed natively.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:text>{&#10;"countries"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after(., '&quot;countryList&quot;')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="search-string">&#10;"country</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="replace-string">&#10;"</xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $search-string)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $search-string)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replace-string"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $search-string)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hey this worked like a charm, Thanks a ton!

Comment: To perform multiple replacements using several pairs of find/replace values, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60815422/3016153

Comment: I was using the below to replace two strings - like countryName with CName and countryId with CID:
`<xsl:when test="contains($text, $search-string)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $search-string)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replace-string"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $search-string)"/>
<xsl:with-param name="text2" select="substring-after($text, $search-string-2)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>`
But looks like this doesnot work

Comment: It would be better to post this as a new question with your new requirement.

Comment: Yes its right here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77347886/ml-which-has-json-with-an-array-inside-of-it-iterate-thru-the-json-and-replace